# How to add NOINDEX NOFOLLOW in product page for magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to change my meta tag to NOINDEX and NOFOLLOW for particular page (especially in product detail page) in magento 2. I have tried adding

```
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
```

and also

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
 </reference>
```

In layout update xml but not changing from default how to fix the issue.

P.S.:I need to update via magento 2 backend.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you can use  [event/Observer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html).

Create a small module.

**Fire an Observer an observer on `layout_load_before` event.**
On this event make product details page is `NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW`.

**Event.xml:**

events.xml is located at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend/`
code should be like that

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="add_robot" instance="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Observer\NoindexfollowOnProduct" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

**Observer class**

**NoindexfollowOnProduct.php** is located at `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Observer` and
the code should be like that

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class NoindexfollowOnProduct implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;

    protected $layoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $layoutFactory
        ) {
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $fullActionName = $observer->getFullActionName();
        /* Check Current page  by full action */
        if ($fullActionName == "catalog_product_view"){
                $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
        }

    }

}
```

**Also, this module should have:**

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`.
2. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
3. . `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.json`.

**After adding the event you should  flush the cache.**

Comment: I need to add NOINDEX NOFOLLOW Only for selected product pages not all. Is that possible.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can do for product wish. Inside `if ($fullActionName == "catalog_product_view") ` you can get product object by  `$observer->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info')-.>getProduct()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set "NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" on product level check this extension for details: https://github.com/28software/module-seo

I create product attribute 'meta_robots'. Depending on the value it changes `<meta name="robots" content="{Chosen attribute value}"/>`

Here is the main logic:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 28Software (https://28software.com)
 * See LICENSE for the license details.
 */
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace TESoftware\Seo\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config as PageConfig;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\RendererInterface;
use TESoftware\Seo\Model\Config\Source\MetaRobots as MetaRobotsSource;

class AddProductMetaRobots
{
    private Http $request;    
    private PageConfig $pageConfig;
    private Registry $registry;

    private const META_ROBOTS = [
        MetaRobotsSource::INDEX_FOLLOW     => 'INDEX,FOLLOW',
        MetaRobotsSource::NOINDEX_FOLLOW   => 'NOINDEX,FOLLOW',
        MetaRobotsSource::INDEX_NOFOLLOW   => 'INDEX,NOFOLLOW',
        MetaRobotsSource::NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW => 'NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW',
    ];

    public function __construct(
        Http $request,
        PageConfig $pageConfig,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->pageConfig = $pageConfig;
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * @param RendererInterface $subject
     *
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeRenderMetadata(RendererInterface $subject): array
    {
        if ($this->getFullActionName() === 'catalog_product_view') {
            $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
            $metaRobotsKey = (int)$product->getData('meta_robots');
            if (isset(self::META_ROBOTS[$metaRobotsKey])) {
                $this->pageConfig->setRobots(self::META_ROBOTS[$metaRobotsKey]);
            }
        }

        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get full action name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullActionName()
    {
        return $this->request->getFullActionName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```